# Can't import Flutter module with Swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

When I import Flutter in Swift, Xcode is telling me `No Such Module 'Flutter'`
[image]

I have noticed there are `Pods` and `Development Pods` directories. Flutter resides in `Development Pods`.

[image]

Other modules in `Pods` are accessible.

Here is my Podfile:

```
# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

platform :ios, '14.0'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  
  pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift/CoreML' #, '~> 0.0.1-nightly'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the contents of pod file?

Comment: @Biclops added podfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shot in the dark but did you try just blowing everything out and seeing if pods fixes itself?

1. go into the ios folder
2. delete the Podfile.lock file
3. rm -rf Pods
4. pod cache clean --all
5. pod deintegrate
6. pod setup
7. pod install

Comment: Another guess is to blow out the pod file itself, and run the command that generated the podfile. Did you use flutter build ios or flutter build ipa to make the podfile?

Comment: I did something similar to your shot in the dark and it worked. The Podfile was created by flutter. Thank you for your service.

Comment: Please mark this answer as the one that worked for you, if you think my answer will help others. It encourages me and others to help others on Stack overflow.

Comment: https://ibb.co/7p8JXnJ

Comment: Did you guys just solve this problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92337 ??